# How to add next and previous in a quiz [python]

Tags: python, testing

I've got the following code that converts a list into a multiple choice quiz:

```
def practise_test(test):
    score = 0
    for question in test:
        while True:
            print(question[question])
            reaction = input (question[options] + '\n')
            if reaction == question[answer]:
                print ('\nright answered!')
                print('The answer is indeed {}. {}\n'.format(question[answer], question[explanation]))
                score += 1
                break      
            else:
                print ('\nIncorrect answer.')
                print ('The correct answer is {}. {}\n'.format(question[answer], question[explanation]))
                break
    print (score)
```

But now I have to add some code to the `practise_test` function so that when you type: 'previous' you go to the previous question. Anyone have an idea to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ktb for the 'next question' part I deleted the while True statement and added a if statement: if reaction == 'next': continue. But I don't think this is the best way and I have no idea for the 'previous question' method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exchange the for loop with a while loop and change the index i in case the user writes "previous". Btw. the double loop you are using seems unnecessary to me.

```
example_test = [
        {"question": "1 + 1", "answer": "2", "explanation": "math", "options": "2, 4, 6, 8"},
        {"question": "2 + 2", "answer": "4", "explanation": "math", "options": "2, 4, 6, 8"},
        {"question": "3 + 3", "answer": "6", "explanation": "math", "options": "2, 4, 6, 8"},
        {"question": "4 + 4", "answer": "8", "explanation": "math", "options": "2, 4, 6, 8"},
        ]

def practise_test(test):
    score = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(test):
        question = test[i]

        print(question["question"])
        reaction = input(question["options"] + '\n')
        if reaction == question["answer"]:
            print ('\nright answered!')
            print('The answer is indeed {}. {}\n'.format(question["answer"], question["explanation"]))
            score += 1
        elif reaction.startswith("previous"):
            i -= 2
            i = max(i, -1)
        else:
            print ('\nIncorrect answer.')
            print ('The correct answer is {}. {}\n'.format(question["answer"], question["explanation"]))
        i += 1
    print (score)

practise_test(example_test)
```

What also seems to be missing is using the dictionary keys as string, but that is just as guess as I do not know the remaining implementation.

Comment: When I try this, it stops after the first question. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I added an example of how I think the structure of the test looks like and added the quotation marks to the dictionary keys. If it does not work now, show an example of how your test looks like.